# What Chemical Could This Represent

Tags: organic-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry, materials, dna-rna

Update
I found someone else who has been trying to solve the same problem and they said that my drawing was not correct. We had a discussion and I conceded that his monochrome picture is more square on and what he was saying had merit. I have updated the drawing to reflect the changes. All black is the monochrome image the red is just notational information.[image: element drawing updated with new information]I have this drawing that looks like a chemical but I have no idea what it is.
It is a bit of a detective story because I have very little information to go on.
Could this be a chemical? If so what chemical/s?
If not any other Idea's?
Each circle is the same size.
120Deg index.
All equal distance from each other.
From the original picture it looks like the distance between each circle is a circles distance. So if a circle was 20 units in diameter then from center to center would be 40 units or 20 units from edge of one to the edge of the next. The image I have is at an angle so making this difficult but I believe this is correct. I have re-drawn the image as accurately as I could.
The drawing is all I have to go on. I am 56 years young and have not looked at chemistry like this since school so I am not much good to myself so need help.[image: Image in question that could be a chemical]

Comment: It is just like the ancients who saw Gemini, a little dipper and a big dipper in the stars in the sky. I don't think it represents anything. It is a nice design.

Comment: Protonated [guanidine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guanidine), maybe?

Comment: It can be too many things, if each circle represent a more complex units than an element

Comment: I did find [boron amide](https://imgur.com/M1dTu4C), $\ce{B(NH2)3}$. See pdf here: https://pubs.rsc.org/en/Content/ArticlePDF/2011/NJ/C0NJ00517G?page=Search

Comment: While further researching this I have come across additional information that proved my drawing incorrect. This caused the post to be closed. I started the post again with just the updated information. https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/138766/what-chemical-could-this-be

Comment: @Craig Instead of asking a new question, update this question with new diagrams. I am sure editing might re-open your question. BTW, did you went through my linked pdf in my above comment? Does that compound suit your needs?

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to be definitive with such a simple picture.

But, if we assume the colour code is black for carbon and that hydrogens have been omitted, the simplest answer is (to use a non-systematic name) tri-isopropyl methane. See [this (very basic) description](http://www.molbase.com/en/name-triisopropylmethane.html) for systematic names.

Comment: Do you think the "molecule" is not flat?

Comment: @JamesGaidis Chemists draw flat, simplified pictures of 3D molecules all the time (especially if they can leave out the hydrogens). On my assumed structure the molecules is clearly not flat.

Comment: I also would assume that it is not flat but a representation of a chemical. The moderator closed this post after I updated it with new information that became available to me and my original drawing was proven to be incorrect.

Comment: The new post can be found here https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/138766/what-chemical-could-this-be